# Python-Firebase (401) Unauthorised error

Tags: python, authentication, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Been trying to retrieve data from my firebase however I keep getting `HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized.` Been using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2 as a guide. Tried adjusting the authentication code but got nowhere. How would I retrieve data from my firebase

```
from firebase import firebase

firebase =  firebase.FirebaseApplication('(my firebase url)',None)

result = firebase.get('/User',None)

print (result)
```

Comment: In my case the app worked in debug but after creating the standlaone executalble with PyInstaller it failed, I realized the Project Tree path was wrong, so I corrected that and now it works alright. Also ensure that private-key.json is in the same path

Answer (score 1):

Go to in Firebase Console > Database >Rules and change

```
 ".read": "auth != null",
 ".write": "auth != null"
```

to:

```
".read": "auth == null",
".write": "auth == null"
```

Comment: Please explain what this does - sounds dangerous to me to just set read and write permissions to unautorized!

Comment: This code effectively removes authentication. Would not recommend!

Answer (score 1):

Provide the authentication information to firebase,

```
from firebase import firebase
authentication = firebase.FirebaseAuthentication('YOUR SECRET', 'user@gmail.com', extra={'id': 123})
fireapp = firebase.FirebaseApplication('DATABASE_URL',  authentication=authentication)
```

and make sure the database rules are,

```
 ".read": "auth != null",
 ".write": "auth != null"
```